# The term 'Update-Database' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations, entity-framework-5

I am using EF5 beta1 and while I was able to run the "Update-Database" before.  Now that I shut down Visual Studio, I cannot get it to run.  I get the following error:

> The term 'Update-Database' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>   At line:1 char:16
>   + Update-Database <<<<  -verbose
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Update-Database:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

I have tried to re-install EF5b1 and while was successful (already installed), the 'Update-Database' still does not work.

Can anyone help???

Comment: Yesterday I had a similar problem with a different cmdlet, and a complete system restart helped...

Comment: Reboot is not necessary. We don’t run init.ps1 scripts after performing package restore (that's why the command was not found). Simply exit and restart VS (or unload/reload the project).

Comment: I had this happen to me today.  I opened a repo for a team project and it needed to restore some packages.  After the restore, the `update-database` and `add-migration` commands wouldn't work.  Restarting Visual Studio fixed it.

Comment: Add `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` to the web project

Comment: I got on this page but for me `UpdateDatabase`  should be `Update-Database`

Answer (score 191):

The solution is to close the Package Manager Console, close Visual Studio and then reopen them.

Rebooting also worked most of the time, but not always.

Comment: Usually you just need to exit restart VS. See my comments in the original question. On rare occasions you might need to exit/restart VS twice.

Comment: Just faced the problem and restarted Visual Studio and things were working again. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, for an effective, if not crappy solution. It seems to be all that works out of a million things I've tried.

Comment: Yes, of course. This is the solution. Legit solution. Thank you Microsoft!

Comment: I installed "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.1.0" on my data projects and "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.1.0" on my main web project, that resolved issue for me.

Comment: That was it for me Habo.  Thanks.  You should add that as an answer instead of comment

Comment: Need to do it 2 times.. but work

Answer (score 62):

For anyone who is using .Net Core and EntityFrameworkCore:

You will need to install `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` package to resolve this issue.

Read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell

Comment: This worked for me. After install this pack, i had a problem at packs, then i ran "msbuild -t:restore". If you have a problem with authentication at this command, then run => msbuild -t:restore -p:NuGetInteractive="true".

Answer (score 56):

If you use Entity Framework:

**Error Message:**

> *"Error Message (from the Update-Database command in the PMC):
> The term 'Update-Database' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."*

**Solution:**

Exit Visual Studio. Reopen project and try again.

For more information please visit: [Advanced Entity Framework 6 Scenarios for an MVC 5 Web Application (12 of 12)](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/advanced-entity-framework-scenarios-for-an-mvc-web-application)

Comment: VS developer team should give Refresh VS button for such issues :)

Comment: @sohaibjaved For some issues, restarting VS would not be enough and some directory cleaning is needed as indicated on [Visual Studio 2015 extremely slow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34395686/visual-studio-2015-extremely-slow/34450140?noredirect=1#comment67102254_34450140). FYI...

Comment: i lost count of how many things are solved by restarting visual studio

Answer (score 27):

Reinstalling the nuget package fixed this issue for me

ie, execute

```
Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 5.0.0
```

in the package manager

Comment: This works for me. The project I worked on used EF and I automatically assume the package was installed. Turned out, it wasn't. The developer just referenced directly to EF dll. EntityFramework package must be installed in the project for Update-Database cmd to work.

Comment: This answer seems unlikely to help however it it saved my day. Thanks,

Comment: Wrestling with FK's today using Fluent API, etc. and somehow EntityFramework keeps getting dropped. What actually worked for me along these lines was to do yet another `Update-Package -Reinstall EntityFramework`.

Comment: for me reinstall and reboot. just reinstall dont work, and just reboot dont work either)

Answer (score 21):

Sometimes when I load VS, I see this in my package manager console:

> Value cannot be null.
>
> Parameter name: path1

I have no idea what causes that yet but it seems that something goes wrong during the start-up of the Powershell console which interrupts the registering of specific modules, such as the EF powershell extensions. You can just manually load it however:

```
Import-Module .\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.1\tools\EntityFramework.psm1
```

Make sure you replace 6.1.1 with whatever your current version of Entity Framework is.

Comment: Thank you! Only solution that worked for me. However, for anyone using EF 6.1.3 with VS 2015 there is a bug in EntityFramework.psm1 and there's a patch available here http://stackoverflow.com/a/30062684/1267778.

Answer (score 13):

you will get this error when the EF tools are not installed properly.

try  the below command in Nuget package manager
//Uninstalls and install the same Version of EF

```
Update-Package "EntityFramework" -reinstall
```

If you still face the same issue.
 create a new Web Project and  run the below command in nuget.

> (Note : no need to create the new Project in the same solution or
>   same location.)

// This will update EF to latest version(including the tools)
 // if you want to use specific version ,  use the `-version` flag.

```
Update-Package "EntityFramework"
```

Once this is done, chcek your original project and you can delete the newly created project.

Comment: Yes!! Thanks =) I only had EntityFramwork, EF.Design, EF.SqlServer and EF.SqlServer.Design installed.

Answer (score 10):

Just restart Visual Studio, it'll solve the problem. Works for me.

Comment: It's really funny how restarting my PC works for this issue

Answer (score 9):

Install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools solved the issue for me, used nuget packages

Answer (score 6):

I solved this by uninstalling and reinstalling `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools`

Comment: If you're using EF Core, this is the correct answer.  Or at least, the problem for me was that `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` was not installed.

Answer (score 4):

I had this same problem, and the origin of it was on my path name, I had on my path a directory name with straight brackets, like this: `C:\[PROJ]\TestApp`.

When I removed the brackets, to `C:\PROJ\TestApp`, it started to work just fine...

Comment: Usually you just need to exit restart VS. See my comments in the original question.

Comment: @RickAndMSFT This is a lot closer to a better solution that "just" restarting VS.

Comment: @Antonio Even I had the same problem and your solution worked for me as well.

Answer (score 4):

Just ReOpen visual studio is work for me

Answer (score 4):

For me the problem was the **Nuget version**.

1. uninstall Nuget Package Manager.
2. restart Visual Studio.
3. installed new version of Nuget Package Manager.
4. then re-start Visual Studio again.

Comment: This was the case for me but I just needed to update nuget in extensions and update

Comment: this worked for me, uninstalled nuget package manager, re installed nuget package manager, restarted visual studio, uninstalled EntityFramework, re installed EntityFramework

Answer (score 2):

This problem seems to happen when you open the project directly from File Explorer.  Try starting VS first and then opening the project - worked for me.  I'm guessing this is about access to paths.

Comment: after restarting a few times and not getting it resolved, this helped solve my issue!

Answer (score 1):

For me it turns out EntityFramework core was not installed on my project (because i started with blank project). So installing **EntityFramework** package resolved the problem. Sometimes if EntityFramework installation failed then try to install individual packages one by one

E.g.

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time those beta versions have some issues, also if Entity Framework failed to load and also this can happen if you are install the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools globally. try to install it locally into your project
. you can try these steps until you fix the issue. and remember this method is not to fix the issue this is the other way to do this.

1. `cd` in to your project directory. not the sln directory to the project directory.
2. then `dotnet ef` to find out that you have correctly install the Entity Framework.
3. then use `dotnet ef migrations add "ReplaceThisWithSomeText"` command. And this will create new migration.
4. then use `dotnet ef database update` to update the database.

[Migrations Overview. This will helps too..](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli)

[Windows commands - cd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cd)

(This Is for EFCore projects)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I did the following:
- restored missing NuGet packages by clicking "Restore" button on top of the Package Manager Console
- restarted Visual Studio
- run `update-database`

Answer (score 0):

Restoring NuGet package didn't help me.

I had to reinstall package manager - https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4ec1526c-4a8c-4a84-b702-b21a8f5293ca

Answer (score 0):

If the other answers don't work (VS 2017): clear the NuGet cache, restart VS, then restore the packages.

Answer (score 0):

I found that it was due to a corrupt package. I had installed Automapper when it was already installed. It was only clear that this package was corrupt when I tried to install another package.

Removing the corrupt package solved this issue for me.

You can then reinstall automapper. The issue was with version 5.4, I am now happily on 6.0.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by updateing Package Manager Console.

I was not getting Update-Database in Package Manager Console. Then i restart several time. Also restart Windows.

Then I download new one from [nuget](https://www.nuget.org) and then it was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in Visual Studio 2015 and resolved it by updating the version of Nuget.

Tools -> Extensions and Updates -> Updates -> Visual Studio Gallery

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix for me was to make sure there was a dash between update and database, like this: `update-database` and use lowercase. It may be coincidental, but when I did this in Packet Manager Console, the database actually updated and I got the done message rather than the `not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file` error.

Answer (score 0):

I started having the same issue after I accidentally opened a Visual Studio solution with Visual Studio 2015 instead of 2017. The project worked just fine before that mishap. It was an older project with EF 5.0 and not EF Core.

I tried everything suggested - restarted Visual Studio countless times, cleaned up NuGet cache, deleted everything in packages folder, reinstalled EF 5 for the project - no good, add-migration was not recognized. If I upgraded EF to 6, it started to recognize the commands, but I did not want to upgrade yet. So, as soon as I reverted back to EF 5, the problem returned.

The only thing that finally saved me was to do the following:

- close Visual Studio
- delete everything from packages folder
- delete .vs folder in the root of your solution. This folder is usually hidden, you have to turn on Show hidden files and folders setting or check Hidden items in folder View tab
- start Visual Studio and open your solution. It will ask to restore NuGet packages, agree to it.

Now EF commands finally started working again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case:

- Reload project did not help
- Restart VS did not help
- Restart computer did not help
- Reinstal EF did not help

But I found an [article](https://www.jeffscorner.org/entity-framework-update-database-not-recognized/) where suggestion was to manualy import missing EF package, using PM Conole:

*`Import-Module .\packages\EntityFramework.X.X.X\tools\EntityFramework.psm1`*

And this solution solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case restarting Visual Studio *(many, many times)* did not work, then as I was looking elsewhere I found a message on the output terminal:

> The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 2.2. Either
>   target .NET Core 2.1 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that
>   supports .NET Core 2.2.

So I installed the required version of .NET Core and the command ran successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in VS 2019 with an existing project using EntityFramework 6.3.0.  This project had some strange version changes done to it over a period of time, and nothing would get it working.  I believe I tried every suggestion listed here with no luck.

Finally, updating to the pre-release version of EntityFramework (currently 6.4.0-preview3-19553-01) did fix the problem, by running this in the Package Manager Console: `Update-Package EntityFramework -prerelease`.  I'm hopeful that when this version is released live in the next few weeks it will work properly.

Answer (score 0):

this is an old issue but as I encountered this today I will add an updated solution
For entity Framework 7, make sure that you have installed:

```
EntityFramework.core
EntityFramework.Tools
EntityFramework.Design
```

then you are safe to run it

Answer (score -1):

For me the problem was the Nuget version.

I removed and re-installed Nuget then re-started Visual Studio and then all started working.