# Visual Studio 2015 RC Entity Framework 6.1.3 Migrations Error

Tags: c#, .net, migration, entity-framework-6, visual-studio-2015

The pasted below error only occurs when the solution has more than one project that references the EntityFramework.
When run the "Enable-Migrations" or "Add-Migration", I received the following error:

> New-Object : The value supplied is not valid, or the property is
>   read-only. Change the value, and then try again. At
>   D:\Projetos\Monitoramento\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:757
>   char:13
>   +     $info = New-Object System.AppDomainSetup -Property @{
>   +             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [New-Object], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SetValueException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand   The
>   property 'PrivateBinPath' cannot be found on this object. Verify that
>   the property exists and can be set. At
>   D:\Projetos\Monitoramento\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:772
>   char:9
>   +         $info.PrivateBinPath += ';lib\net45'
>   +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound   Exception calling "LoadFrom" with "1" argument(s): "The specified path, file name, or
>   both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260
>   characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters."
>   At
>   D:\Projetos\Monitoramento\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:780
>   char:5
>   +     $utilityAssembly = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom((Join-Path $ToolsP ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathTooLongException   You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At
>   D:\Projetos\Monitoramento\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:781
>   char:5
>   +     $dispatcher = $utilityAssembly.CreateInstance(
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull   Exception calling "CreateInstanceFrom" with "8" argument(s): "The specified path, file
>   name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less
>   than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248
>   characters." At
>   D:\Projetos\Monitoramento\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:809
>   char:5
>   +     $domain.CreateInstanceFrom(
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathTooLongException

Output with EntityFramework 6.1.1:

> Exception calling "LoadFrom" with "1" argument(s): "The specified
>   path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name
>   must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less
>   than 248 characters." At C:\Users\Hudson\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\WpfApplication4\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.1\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:780
>   char:5
>   +     $utilityAssembly = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom((Join-Path $ToolsP ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathTooLongException   You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At
>   C:\Users\Hudson\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\WpfApplication4\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.1\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:781
>   char:5
>   +     $dispatcher = $utilityAssembly.CreateInstance(
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull   Exception calling "CreateInstanceFrom" with "8" argument(s): "The specified path, file
>   name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less
>   than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248
>   characters." At C:\Users\Hudson\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\WpfApplication4\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.1\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:809
>   char:5
>   +     $domain.CreateInstanceFrom(
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathTooLongException

Comment: FYI there is now a workaround for this - https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/1950#issuecomment-99343541

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Other solution: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/1950#issuecomment-99164398

Copy [this patched version of EntityFramework.psm1](https://www.codeplex.com/Download/AttachmentDownload.ashx?ProjectName=entityframework&WorkItemId=2743&FileAttachmentId=1454797).

Comment: I had to copy and paste the content of the script rather than replacing the file, otherwise I get an error that the script isn't digitally signed. Otherwise that worked, cheers.

Comment: @MIP1983 if you replace the file, then you'll need to 'Unblock' from file properties.. worked for me ;)

Comment: Worked like a charm. However, I still had some other problem with EF loading up in the first place so I had to load up the EF module manually via:  `Import-Module .\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1 `

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem :(

My workaround is:

1. Downgrade Entity Framework to v6.1.1 (at least the new NuGet GUI makes this very easy)
2. Run the command (for example `Add-Migration ...`) on the package manager console. It seems to work in this version
3. Upgrade back to Entity Framework v6.1.3

Comment: I followed all the steps, but the problem has not been resolved. Works only if you have one project with installed EntityFramework. If you have more than one, after following the steps mentioned, not resolved.
I tried to run as Administrator, not resolved.

Comment: Oh :( I, too, have several projects with EF installed in the solution, I did the downgrade only on the project that contains the migrations. Could you try to delete the `packages` directory and completely restore all the packages beforehand. I did that while playing around, too, but didn't think that it helped my workaround in any way.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a common issue, but apparently difficult to repo?

[Enable-migrations error #1950](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/1950)

Suggest you add your issue details to the above in the hopes that it can be resolved quickly.

Answer (score 1):

As per [comment by yishaigalatzer](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/1950#issuecomment-108709646) on EF bug #1950, NuGet 3.0 RC2 has now been released, which should fix this problem. Simply download the VSIX from [codeplex](https://nuget.codeplex.com/releases/view/615507) and install it.

This solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I just:


 1. Closed VS.

 2. Removed Entity Framework package in packages folder manually.

 3. Opened project and restored packages.


That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found a temporary solution:
Comment `<package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net46" userInstalled="true" />` of all its "packages.config" leaving uncommented only the project you want to work with Migrations.

The Team EntityFramework (https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/1950) and NuGet (https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/528) are aware of the problem and we will soon have a solution final.