# Add Assembly to Class Library in VS 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, class-library

Have used Visual Studio for years and are now trying to create my first project in Visual Studio 2015.

I have create an MVC project and I am now interrested in adding a new project which will act as my data layer. Lets call the project MyProj. So I created a new Web Class Library called MyProj.Data. I also installed the newest EntityFramework (6.1.3) using NuGet to this project.

Now I want to create a class which should act as my EntityTypeConfiguration like:

```
public class GadgetConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Gadget>
{
  ....
}
```

Problem is that EntityTypeConfiguration is not recognised. Reharper says: Reference 'EntityFramework' and use 'System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.EntityTypeConfiguration'

Problem is that (as far as I see it) in folder References -> .NET Platform I can see my EntityFramework. So that should be referenced. But I cannot find System.Data.Entity in the references.

When I try to Add Reference, my Assemblies tab say 'No items found'. If I click the "Browse..." button I am told that "Project does not have target frameworks specified".

Then I tried adding v4.5 to the MyProj.Data.xproj file (under ...) but that didn't change a thing.

Then I changed the frameworks part of the project.json file from

```
"frameworks": {
 "dotnet": { }
 }
```

to

```
"frameworks": {
"dotnet": { },
"dnx451": {
  "frameworkAssemblies": {
    "System.Data": "4.0.0.0",
    "System.Data.Entity": "4.0.0.0"
  }
}
```

Now I can see the System.Data and System.Data.Entity. I can also add more assemblies from the References now. But I still cannot USE them in my classes. Neither by typing

```
using EntityFramework
```

or

```
using System.Data
```

or by referencing directly like

```
public class GadgetConfiguration : System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.EntityTypeConfiguration<Gadget>
```

How can I reference/use the needed assembly?

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30030521/visual-studio-2015-rc-entity-framework-6-1-3-migrations-error

Answer (score 3):

Okay, solution was simple...
I Created a Web Class Library which is to be used when you want to create a class library as a NuGet package. This was NOT what I wanted (you couldn't know from my initial description).

So solution was to drop the Web Class Library and create a Windows Class Library instead. It now works!

Comment: I had a similar problem. My solution was similar. I first created a .net core class library. When I opened up just a .net class library, it worked.